# How can I fetch images from my private team?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, images, api

I need to fetch some of the private team's images via the API or HTTPS, but I am not able to do this.

I see this [feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/8140/enable-access-to-post-images-in-the-api-for-stack-overflow-for-teams) from StackApps, but I am posting this as a Stack Overflow for Teams client and I think it should belong here.

Is there any decent way to achieve this? By decent I mean using the API or HTTPS, not some UI automation like Selenium.

**Question:** How can I fetch images from my private team?

Comment: What images are you wanting to get? Even for the main sites:  the SE API doesn't provide downloads of images. You can use it to get URLs for user's avatars, but getting images from posts would require you to parse either the Markdown or HTML of the post. You can get those (Markdown and/or HTML) from the SE API (for main and meta sites, but not Teams). So, A) it's not clear what you want, and B) even for the main and meta sites there isn't a direct way to "fetch images" (whatever that actually means).

Comment: @Makyen - when you upload the image to a private team, they will not be uploaded to a public location, but within your team's space. The URL will look like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team_id}/images/s/{guid}.png. These are accessible by GET request only when logged in (browser). If I want to link to these images into some Intranet location, they are accessible only to private team members. If I want to sync them, there seems to be no easy way to do this.

Comment: If you are a team admin, you can export your team data. That export includes all the images on your team.

Comment: @g3rv4 - yes, but this is hard to automate. The idea is that I wanted to highlight some posts and mirror them on an internal blog to act as a teaser. I can safely take the text, but images display for logged in users only.

Comment: @g3rv4 - this is actually a good idea until SO provides a decent solution. Thanks.