# Stack Overflow for Teams upgrade from Basic to Business checklist

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

### Context

I am currently evaluating Stack Overflow for Teams Basic and the results are pretty good so far (from the community's perspective), so I am willing to propose upgrading to Business.

In order to fully understand what this means, I would like to clarify a few aspects.

**Note:** I know that one way to do this is by contacting the SO support, but this is clearly applicable to others in the future, so it makes sense to be here. This should also alleviate some support strain since tech support will receive clearer requests and some questions might have already been answered.

### Payment

[The presentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) payment information for Business plan is:

> $11 Per user / month billed annually

**Is there a monthly billing option here?** I expect that licenses count to fluctuate as people come and go in the company, on-board the platform etc.

### SSO

SSO is by far the most desired feature from Business plan. Currently the most e-mail addresses are internal, but some accounts use personal e-mail addresses in order to integrate with personal SO accounts (and benefit from unified notifications and federated search).

**Can the team be migrated to use SSO in this context?**

**Also, is there a hybrid approach? (have SSO and user/pass authentication in the same time)**

### API improvements

AFAIK, Basic and Business Plan use the same Stack Exchange API features that are also available for the public sites. **Are there any benefits API-wise when upgrading to Business Plan?**

Example: A feature that the current API lacks is [not being able to fetch private images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391901/how-can-i-fetch-images-from-my-private-team).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happy to hear that your evaluation has been good so far!

Let's get these questions answered:

#### Payment

Our Business plan does not offer monthly payments.

Having people joining and leaving your Team throughout the year is natural. When calculating your fee, our billing system will consider the amount of users on a monthly basis.

If you've had 20 users for most of the year but 22 users for April and May, those two extra users will only be accounted for these two months (effectively increasing your bill by $44).

#### SSO

If you enable SSO, your users will have to authenticate with the SSO provider in order to get access to your team. This does not affect their current account on Stack Overflow, as the SSO credentials will simply be added to their existing account.

We do not allow a hybrid approach for signing in. Once you've activated SSO, all users have to sign in using your SSO provider. While this may seem like a limitation, this is intended to make access to your Team more secure and easier to maintain for your Team admins (they can be certain that users deactivated on your SSO provider lose access to your Team, too).

### API

Compared to the Basic plan, the Business plan gives you *write* access via our API. The Basic plan has access to the same API but is limited to *read-only* access.

---

*(I see the feature request you linked there. We'll have a look at this one and see if we can resolve this quickly!)*

Comment: Do you only send the first bill at the end of the year, or is there an initial estimated bill at the start of the year, followed by an adjustment at years end?

Comment: @DanNeely There is an initial invoice for the number of users you currently have or however many seats you wish to purchase if you know you'll be adding more users. We will generate monthly invoices if you add additional users past the initial purchase. These users will be prorated for the remaining time on your annual contract.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and exhaustive answer. When performing the migration is it possible to also migrate all activity from one user to another. Example: my account is using the public SO account which is connected to a gmail account. Naturally, when migrating to SSO, I would like to migrate to my A/D account since the hybrid approach is not allowed.

Comment: Your user, including all questions, answers, votes, reputation, etc. will remain in place when you upgrade. We add your new SSO credential to your existing account once you start using SSO. This way you can log in with your existing account using your SSO provider. There won't be a new user unless you explicitly create a new one (and even then we could merge them later on).